# g++ Linking vs VisualC++ Linking

Tags: c++, g++, static-linking

I have been trying to get this working for a while now and am unable to find an answer elsewhere, here is my problem.

When I make a static library in Visual C++ any dependencies that this library uses are carried on to the executable program that I link the library to. Here is an example

Test.lib depends on
  - SDL
  - OpenGL

TestApp.exe links Test.lib

In Visual C++ I do not have to add the dependencies for Test.lib in my TestApp executable, they are carried over and it works great.

However when I port my code to Linux g++ (With the Code::Blocks IDE), if I make a Static Library which is .a in g++, and I make a TestApp that links the library, it gets undefined references to the dependencies.

Is g++ able to do this, and if so what am I missing to have the dependencies carried over to my executable?

As for my settings for my library I simply use the IDE's Static Library setting.

Comment: I am linking (In code blocks) by going into build settings, and under linker settings adding -lTestLib where my library is named libTestLib.a , in Visual Studio I just add the library to the dependencies as normal

Comment: I do not use any command line stuff, just what the IDE shows in the linker settings, it offers the option to browse for the file or just specify the name of the file

Comment: And how are you linking TestLib in VS with SDL, OpenGL? You need to pack .o files of SDL and GL together with an ar tool, together with your TestLib.o

Comment: In Visual Studio I simply set my project to Static library and set all the libraries I wish to use, the default settings automatically carry my dependencies over to any project that uses the library. 

So when I make my static library with Code Blocks, it isn't actually putting my SDL, OpenGL and TestLib libraries together? I need to do this mannually?

Comment: Yes. On windows you probably resolve the references because SDL.dll and opengl32.dll are in the system env path.

Comment: Yes but what about projects that do not use dll's such as TinyXML, I build this project as a static library and use the TinyXML.lib in my other static library, I do not have to specify TinyXML.lib in my project however, as it seems to automatically link this in.

Comment: They do not depend on other libraries?

Comment: Not as far as I believe, that wouldn't be the point though, if TinyXML has a function implemented in a cpp file for its static library say TiXmlDocument::LoadFile , this function is automatically passed from the TinyXML lib to my Static Lib to my program, if this wasn't the case then my program would say undefined reference to TiXmlDocument::LoadFile (At the linker phase)

Comment: That's true. But TinyXml doesn't depend on SDL (dynamic library), say. It's what's in your case.

Comment: No but I have a Game Engine built as a static library, it uses SDL, OpenGL and TinyXML to name a few, in Visual C++ I do not have to link these in my executable project, only in my Game Engine Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Microsoft's compiler, header files can have library dependency information in them (source files, too, but this is typically done in headers); this gets compiled into the object file, and the linker understands and applies that information. That can be handy: you don't have to remember long, funky names, and if you compile two source files with incompatible options you may get a library name conflict that the linker will complain about. Most compilers and linkers don't do this kind of thing, and you have to tell the linker explicitly which libraries you want to link with.

Comment: Well that explains it. Can you link to a source that mentions this?

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, if I REALLY have to link the libraries in GCC for my library and application I will, I was hoping there was some way to duplicate the behaviour of the vc++ compiler, but if not it is fine

Comment: @iccthedral - it's been several years since I had to deal with this stuff, and I don't remember the details. But the library information comes from one of their pragma's, maybe it even mentions "library" in the name.

Comment: @MSalters - that looks familiar. `<g>`

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries do not statically link with other libraries. Does that sound right?
However you can pack many object files together with a tool called [ar](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ar.htm).

What happens on windows is probably because you have the (SDL, opengl32) dlls somewhere in a system env path.

Comment: Maybe add that DLL's are not static libraries and that the OP needs to manually include the library dependencies with gcc

Comment: Ok, so here is another scenario that is different, I have a static library in windows of TinyXML, there is no DLL and everything is statically linked, in my Application project I do not need to add the dependency for TinyXML as it is in my static library, however in GCC it does not do this

Comment: @AdrianCornish - it's true that DLLs are not static libraries, but every DLL has a corresponding static library that holds information about its exported names, and you have to link with that library in order to use the DLL (unless you're going to load it by hand and manually look up entry points).

Comment: @PeteBecker: That's actually a limitation of Microsoft's linker, not of DLL's. MinGW can actually link DLLs without those static "import" libs